# How to invert a right triangle (Java)

Tags: java

i have a nested loop that prints a triangle of numbers like so:

```
123
12
1
```

and i need an another triangle, but it has to be inverted so the two can make an empty triangle underneath, like so:

```
12321
12 21
1   1
```

Here is my loop for the first one:

```
for (i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
    System.out.println();
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

I added another loop:

```
for (j = n; j >= 1; j--) {
    System.out.print(j); 
}
```

and the numbers are now reversed, but repeated, like so:

```
123321
12321
1321
```

Comment: it can be easy though IMHO i would recommend trying little more

Comment: Hint: You need more conditions & logic within the inner loop. (To "decrement" `j` back down to `1`)

Comment: @cricket_007 do i need to consider spacing?

Comment: Eventually, yes. Just try to get the numbers working first

Comment: @cricket_007 ive got them to reverse, but they dont decrement. the same numbers repeat on each line..

Comment: [Edit] the question please, with the latest output and code

Comment: @cricket_007 edited

Comment: I added some code for you. Enjoy your programming learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
int n = 3;
for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = n - 1; j > -n; j--) {
        int k = n - Math.abs(j);
        if (k <= i) {
            System.out.print(k);
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

How is it work? Let's simplify the code:

```
int n = 3;
for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = n - 1; j > -n; j--) {
        int k = n - Math.abs(j);
        System.out.print(k);
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

We just print rectangle:

```
12321
12321
12321
```

And now for every i row we need print number that k <= i.

```
int n = 3;
for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = n - 1; j > -n; j--) {
        int k = n - Math.abs(j);
        if (k <= i) {
            System.out.print(k);
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

And have:

```
12321
12 21
1   1
```

Comment: can you please explain your logic? your thought process?

Comment: How I see my logic seems with logic @Marko Topolnik.

Answer (score 0):

I would describe what you want to do in the following way:

1. Print `n-i-1` numbers asc.
2. print i spaces.
3. if i == 0 print n, else print space.
4. print n-i-1 numbers desc

Implementation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
        System.out.print(j+1);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print(i == 0 ? n : " ");
    for (int k = n-i-1; k > 0; k--) {
        System.out.print(k);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly "smarter" solution:

```
for (int i = 3; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (int j = -2; j <= 2; j++) {
        final int toPrint = 3 - Math.abs(j);
        System.out.print(toPrint <= i ? Integer.toString(toPrint) : " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

It uses `abs` so it can use a single inner loop for the 1-2-3-2-1 sequence and it decides whether to print the number or space by comparing with row number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compact optimized version using a single `char[]`:

```
private static void printHollowTriangle(int size) {
    char[] buf = new char[size * 2 - 1];
    for (int i = 0, j = buf.length - 1; i <= j; i++, j--)
        buf[i] = buf[j] = Character.forDigit(i + 1, Character.MAX_RADIX);
    for (int i = size - 1, j = size - 1; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
        System.out.println(buf);
        buf[i] = buf[j] = ' ';
    }
}
```

It can print valid triangles of size 1 to 35. See examples at the end.

The logic goes like this:

- All lines are the same length, so a single `char[]` of the right size can be used.
- The first line is built by assigning incrementing numbers from the beginning *and* from the end, until they meet in the middle. The middle character is double-assigned, but adding `if` statement to skip that will just complicate the code for no benefit.

  The incrementing single-digit numbers are done in base-36, so it can handle triangles up to size 35.

  Code should technically throw `IllegalArgumentException` for `size` values outside the supported range of 1-35.
- Print the first line with all the numbers.
- All subsequent lines are mostly same as previous line, except that center blank region is increased in size, so simply blank out two more characters on each iteration. First iteration will double-assign again, but no problem, like before.
- To save a `print` statement, the printing is actually done at the beginning of the loop, so the last iteration will build an entirely blank line but it is not printed.

As promised, here is example output:

**`printHollowTriangle(1);`**

```
1
```

**`printHollowTriangle(2);`**

```
121
1 1
```

**`printHollowTriangle(3);`**

```
12321
12 21
1   1
```

**`printHollowTriangle(35);`**

```
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy yxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx   xwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw     wvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv       vutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstu         utsrqponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrst           tsrqponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrs             srqponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqr               rqponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmnopq                 qponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmnop                   ponmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmno                     onmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklmn                       nmlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijklm                         mlkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijkl                           lkjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghijk                             kjihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghij                               jihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefghi                                 ihgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefgh                                   hgfedcba987654321
123456789abcdefg                                     gfedcba987654321
123456789abcdef                                       fedcba987654321
123456789abcde                                         edcba987654321
123456789abcd                                           dcba987654321
123456789abc                                             cba987654321
123456789ab                                               ba987654321
123456789a                                                 a987654321
123456789                                                   987654321
12345678                                                     87654321
1234567                                                       7654321
123456                                                         654321
12345                                                           54321
1234                                                             4321
123                                                               321
12                                                                 21
1                                                                   1
```